# Can anybody know the HTTP_USER_AGENT for Samsung Galaxy S7?

Tags: android, user-agent, galaxy

We are checking the HTTP_USER_AGENT for our web application(in PHP) and for other android versions and devices returns "Android" for the user agent value.
But there is some issue reported for Galaxy S7 and we don't have the device right now to check the value, also no emulator available for same in chrome.

Is there any way to know the Galaxy S7 user agent value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; SAMSUNG SM-G930F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 2):

There are [a lot different user agents for Samsung Galaxy S7](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=SAMSUNG%20SM-G930F&include=yes&class=brm&do=desc) and not only one. A user can install different browser apps on his device, there are also software updates etc. You can even find more variants of the agent string provided above in this [search](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Linux%3B%20Android%206.0%3B%20SAMSUNG%20SM-G930F%20Build%2FMMB29K%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20SamsungBrowser%2F4.0%20Chrome%2F44.0.2403.133%20Mobile%20Safari%2F537.36&include=yes&class=brm&do=desc).

Comment: The link doesn't gives the Galaxy S7 details

Comment: You were absolute right I missed the specific S7 part in my first answer. I refined the search results and edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, this gives more details.
Do you know the user agent value for S7 with Nougat OS?
Since S7 with marshmallow os  returns "Android", so no issues with code